# How to convert NULL string to \N using sed

Tags: replace, sed

I have `NULL` strings (not NULL chars) in a file. I want to convert all of them to `\N` (string) This is what i tired, which is not working

```
sed "s/NULL/\\N/g" data/fixed/3.csv > data/fixed/4.csv
```

PS : this change is to support MySQL null imports (not to add a new line)
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/null-values.html

Comment: use `\\\N` instead of `\\N`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use single quotes:

```
$ echo 'abc NULL foo NULL' | sed 's/NULL/\\N/g'
abc \N foo \N
```

From http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes

> Single quotes: '...' removes the special meaning of every character
>   between the quotes. Everything inside single quotes becomes a literal
>   string. The only character that you can't safely enclose in single
>   quotes is a single quote.